# Ошибка в подключении к базе данных

Tags: php, mysql

Ошибка: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in X:\home\vik-sait.su\www\engine\functions.php on line 8

Код:

```
<?php 
require_once ("config/database.php");
global $db;
global $ucp_settings;
global $ucp_table_settings;

function message($status,$header, $message, $url = '') {
    exit(json_encode(['status' => $status,'header' => $header, 'message' => $message, 'url' => $url]));
}

function location($url) {
    exit(json_encode(['url' => $url]));
}

function FixName($name)
{
    $order = array("_");
    $replace = " ";
    $newstr = str_replace($order,$replace,$name);
    $pos = strpos($newstr," ",1);
    $name = substr($newstr,0,$pos);
    $subname = substr($newstr,$pos,24);
    echo "".$name." ".$subname."";
}
function GetUserData()
{
    global $db;
    global $ucp_table_settings;

    $name = $_SESSION['NickName'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `{$ucp_table_settings['table']}` WHERE `{$ucp_table_settings['name']}` = '{$name}' LIMIT 1";

    $statement = $db->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute ();
    return $statement->fetch();
}
function getSettingColumn()
{
    global $db;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ucp_table_settings";

    $statement = $db->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute ();

    while($columns = $statement->fetch())
    {
        $content .= "
        <div class=\"form-group\">
                          <label for=\"issueinput1\">Название поля | {$columns['name']}</label>
                          <input type=\"text\" id=\"issueinput1\" class=\"form-control\" value=\"{$columns['value_column']}\"
                          name=\"{$columns['name_column']}\" onChange=\"UpdateTableData(this.getAttribute('name'), this.value);\">
                        </div>

        ";
    }
    return $content;
}

function getUsers() {
    global $db;

    global $ucp_table_settings;

    $sql = "SELECT {$ucp_table_settings['id']} FROM {$ucp_table_settings['table']}";

    $statement = $db->prepare($sql);

    $statement->execute ();

    return $statement->rowCount();
}
function checkPassword() {
    global $db;
    global $ucp_table_settings;
    global $ucp_settings;
    $name = $_SESSION['NickName'];
    $password = $_SESSION['Password'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `{$ucp_table_settings['table']}` WHERE `{$ucp_table_settings['name']}` = '{$name}' LIMIT 1";

    $statement = $db->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute ();

    if($statement->rowCount())
    {
        $data = $statement->fetch();
        if($ucp_settings['s_md5']) 
        {
            if($data[$ucp_table_settings['pass']] != md5($password)) exit("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url= /profile/exit'>");
        }
        else 
        {
            if($data[$ucp_table_settings['pass']] != $password) exit("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url= /profile/exit'>");
        }
    }
    else exit("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url= /profile/exit'>");

}


?>
```

Comment: как ваше "ошибка подключения к БД" соотносится с текстом ошибки, в котором написано: "_ошиба парсера. Синтаксическая ошибка, неожиданный `[`, ожидается `)`_" ?

Comment: похоже, это еще и не тот файл, в котором ошибка - что-то ее тут не видно

Comment: а как тут hash прописать чтоб пороль авторизация такой был 4D9E0BECC69832358FDFAD0A467B54B9